# Finding the minimum of a set of inputs

Tags: java, loops

I've been given Pseudo code to translate into a Java program.

It is as follows:

- Set a Boolean variable “first” to true.
- While another value has been read successfully

  - If first is true

    - Set the minimum to the value just read
    - Set first to false
  - Else if the value is less than the minimum

    - Set the minimum to the value
  - Print the minimum

So far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");

    boolean first = true;
    int min = 0;
    int val = 0;

    while (scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        val = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        if (first == true) 
        {
            min = val;
            first = false;
        } 

        else if (val < min) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            min = val;

        }

        while (!scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println (("The minimum value is") + (min));
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm stumped!

Thanks.

Comment: What are you having trouble on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing great--just keep doing what you're doing.  But here's some stuff you'll need to know to finish:

- The Scanner class documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  There, you'll see that you can call scan.nextInt(), and it'll return you the integer that scan.hasNextInt() has promised.
- You can declare integer values just you're doing for the "first" flag, which when true is denoting that it's the first input is being processed.
- If multiple statements are to be executed "inside" an if clause, you need {}'s, and you can use the else keyword to only execute the next statement if the prior if conditions weren't true.

Let us know if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: +1 for making the OP himself to approach the answer to the problem by just showing the path

Comment: Think I have it now, would be great if you could check the answer, I've edited it above, thanks!

Comment: I just ran your code and it works great--nice!  I had neglected to mention that you were going to need to finalize how you were getting your input in, too, but you figured that out before I could write anything up. :P  Don't forget, if you're going to turn this in as homework, to print something like "Enter an integer (or a non-integer to end the program)", so the user doesn't have to guess or look at the code.